# Extend OIDCLoginProtocol in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect

I want to use the OIDC Login protocol for my client app. But the default implementation of the OIDC Login protocol doesn't meet my requirements. I want to update **authenticated** method of the OIDCLoginProtocol. Is there any simple way to extend OIDC Login Protocol and update only the **authenticated** method of OIDCLoginProtocol.java

Answer (score 3):

Check Keycloak sources if there an SPI for OIDCLoginProtocol. I guess it may be true for latest versions (UPD. Yes it is at least for master branch). If so refer to [Keycloak Development guides](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_providers), how to implement and deploy custom Keycloak Service Provider.

Otherwise you have only a option to fork Keycloak sources, update OIDCLoginProtocol.java as you need and then build custom Keycloak distribution.

Comment: It is possible to create Custom Login Protocol which I did before. But I am looking for an easy way of extending only one method of built-in SPI. The second option is also a good solution but for each new version of Keycloack I need create custom Keycloak distribution. @solveMe

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

- Create a new protocol factory by extending OIDCLoginProtocolFactory

```
public class CustomOIDCLoginProtocolFactory extends OIDCLoginProtocolFactory {
            
                @Override
                public LoginProtocol create(KeycloakSession session) {
                    return new CustomOIDCLoginProtocol().setSession(session);
                }
}
```

- Create a new protocol by extending OIDCLoginProtocol and override the authenticated method.

```
public class CustomOIDCLoginProtocol extends OIDCLoginProtocol {
    
        @Override
        public Response authenticated(AuthenticationSessionModel authSession, UserSessionModel userSession, ClientSessionContext clientSessionCtx) {
```

- Add protocol factory to org.keycloak.protocol.LoginProtocolFactory